# jquery slider playing automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with the coding on the site I'm trying to build.
www.diveintodesign.co.uk/ChrisMcCrone/index.html

The coding is from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

The large image in the middle is the slideshow, the two bars on the left and right of it are the next and previous buttons which work fine but it won't run automatically for some reason, the javascript includes timeout:0

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Cheers,

Lise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting timeout to the amount of time to hold on a slide is what you want.

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 3000, // 3 seconds
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up your code and the `jQuery Cycle Plugin` website. I think you have to change the timeout to a number which is higher than 0, else it doesn't automatically slide.

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 5000,  // time in milliseconds you want
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev' 
});
```

Also, I want to say that it's really not clear that the black bars on the side are the buttons to control the slideshow.

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly! and yes I know the bars aren't clear that's the design, they are meant to be subtle. When it's done they will have the hover over icon.